# Shadow error in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

am using this code to get the shadow effect in my UIViewcontroller
in My ViewDidLoad

```
// Add drop shadow to the view.
        CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, self.view.frame.size.height);
        gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                (id)[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor,
                                (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                                nil];
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(-7, 0.1);
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.15);   
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

i got the correct shadow in the view,but the problem is when i go  to another view controller and comes back the show is getting darker and darker for each time.am using UIPopOverController for navigating to another view.

What is the problem with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you move to next view remove your gradientlayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran some tests with your exact code and it worked correctly. The only way I could replicate the problem you are having is by putting your code into either `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`. Is it possible you have some code in either of those functions that is drawing a shadow?

Comment: haii,thanks for the reply,,,i put this code in viewdidload method

Comment: Hmm. Is there anything that would cause viewDidLoad to be called each time the view comes back? How are you actually transitioning views? UINavigationController?

Comment: I saw that from your post, but without context it doesn't mean a whole lot. Is the shadow on the view *inside* the popover? When someone selects an item in the popover, what happens then? Do they go to another view? If so, what command are you using?

Comment: ,when i select a button in the popover it disappears and change the main page text according to that button click,i put notification to remove the popover..

Comment: not the thing is when i put a shadow image insetd of this code, i get the same error,the image is beaming bigger or darker

Comment: I'm still not seeing what you're doing. Can you post all of the relevant sections of code from your popover controller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11919/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-josh-hudnall)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any help but when I started using UIPopOver controllers I had the exact same situation you were getting.

It was because each time I was activating anew popover I was overlaying it again and again and not removing the old one. So it looks like the shadow was getting darker and darker each time.

Are you removing the PopOver when you move to another view or leaving it behind?

Just a Thought.